# MySQL load data local field termination give error

Tags: mysql

I have a local file structured as follows;

```
E312D72A2D671437F87446170460320B7F0B53CE:1
E31A0888C42FDE105EA887F2EC8DF1ABF5DBFAA0:1
E326561AE42192053CC09D5EA15DE54230AE4510:1
```

I want to load this file into a table. The table has 3 columns `col1,col2`, and `col3`. I'm using the syntax from [dev-mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) as;

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'input.txt' 
   INTO table myTable(col1,col2) FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':';
```

It gives an error as

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':'' at line 1

What is the reason for this error? What is the correct syntax?

And, yes my file has two fields and I want to insert them into a table with 3 columns, the last column can be NULL.

---

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

Comment: Did you try adding a `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly do I have to use both of them together? `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(col1,col2) FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it this way:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'input.txt' 
   INTO table myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' (col1,col2);
```

Comment: Yes, I did. According to the documentation, FIELDS TERMINATED BY should be before the list of columns.